# Brainfuck interpreter written in C

Tags: beginner, c, interpreter, brainfuck

I am a beginner with regards to C; I'm used to using high-level languages (Java, Python, JS, etc) and this is my first project in a lower-level language. I wrote a simple Brainfuck interpreter, given that my Python implementation was super slow.

Here's the code:

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

unsigned char mem[30000] = {0};
unsigned char* ptr = mem;

void goToLoopEnd(char** ip) {
    int searching = 1;

    while (searching > 0) {
        (*ip)++;

        switch (**ip) {
            case '[':
                searching++;
                break;
            case ']':
                searching--;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

void goToLoopStart(char** ip) {
    int searching = 1;

    while (searching > 0) {
        (*ip)--;

        switch (**ip) {
            case ']':
                searching++;
                break;
            case '[':
                searching--;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

void interpret(char* code) {
    char* ip;

    for (ip = code; *ip != '\0'; ip++) {
        switch (*ip) {
            case '>':
                ptr++;
                break;
            case '<':
                ptr--;
                break;
            case '+':
                (*ptr)++;
                break;
            case '-':
                (*ptr)--;
                break;
            case '.':
                putchar(*ptr);
                break;
            case ',':
                *ptr = getchar();
                break;
            case '[':
                if (*ptr == 0) {
                    goToLoopEnd(&ip);
                }
                break;
            case ']':
                if (*ptr != 0) {
                    goToLoopStart(&ip);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // Set to interpret a mandelbrot set fractal viewer in brainfuck written by Erik Bosman.
    interpret("+++++++++++++[->++>>>+++++>++>+<<<<<<]>>>>>++++++>--->>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]+[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>>>>>>>>[-]>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>[-]+<<<<<<<+++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>>+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+[>>>>>>[>>>>>>>[-]>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>[-]+<<<<<<++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>+<<<<<<+++++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[[-]>>>>>>[>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<+<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<+<<<+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<+<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]+>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<[->>[-<<+>>]<<[->>+>>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<<[->>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<<]>>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<-<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>->[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>-<[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<[->+>>>-<<<<]>>>>>>>>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<[-]<<]>>[<<<<<<<+<[-<+>>>>+<<[-]]>[-<<[->+>>>-<<<<]>>>]>>>>>>>>>>>>>[>>[-]>[-]>[-]>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]>>>>>>[>>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>[-<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]+>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<<[->>[-<<+>>]<<[->>+>+<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>[-<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>]<<[->>+<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<<[->>[-<<+>>]<<[->>+>>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<-<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[-]>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>+>[-<-<<<<+>>>>>]>[-<<<<<<[->>>>>+<++<<<<]>>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<->+>]<[->+<]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<]>>>>>>[-]<<<<<<+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>->>>>>[>>[-<<->>]+<<[->>->[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>-<[-<<+>>]<<[->>+<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+>>>>>[>+>>[-<<->>]<<[->>+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->>>>>+<<<<[->>>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[->>>+<<<]<]>[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<<]>[->>>>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>[->>>+<<<]<<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]<<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>>>>>>[>+>[-<->]<[->+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->>>>>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>[->>>>+<<<<]>]<[->>>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]<]>>[->>>+<<<<[->>>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]>]<[->>>>+<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>+<<<<<<]]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[->>>>>+<<<<[->>>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[->>>+<<<]<]>[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<<]>[->>>>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>[->>>+<<<]<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>[-]>>[-]>[-]>>>>>[>>[-]>[-]>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]+>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<[->>[-<<+>>]<<[->>+>+<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>[-<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>]<<[->>+<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>[-]>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<-<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>->[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>-<[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>>>>>>[>+>>>[-<<<->>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->+>[-<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>[-<<+>>]<]>[-<<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>]<<<]>>[-<+>>[-<<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>[-<<+>>]<<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+>>>>>[>+>>[-<<->>]<<[->>+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->+>>[-<<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[-<+>]>]<[-<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<<]>>>[-<<+>[-<-<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]>]<[-<+>]<<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>+<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>[-]>[-]>[-]>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]>[-]>>>>>[>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>+>[-<-<<<<+>>>>>]>>[-<<<<<<<[->>>>>+<++<<<<]>>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<->+>>]<<[->>+<<]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<]+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>->>>>>[>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>-<[-<<+>>]<<[->>+<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>[-<<->>]+<<[->>->[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>>>>>>[>+>[-<->]<[->+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->>>>+<<[->>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>[->>>+<<<]>]<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]<]>>[->>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>]>]<[->>>+<<<]<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>[-]>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<+<<<<<]]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+>>>>>[>+>>[-<<->>]<<[->>+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<+<[>[->>>>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[->>+<<]<]>[->>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<<]>[->>>+<<[->>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>[->>+<<]<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>[-]<<<<]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+>[-]>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<+<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[->>>>+<<<[->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>[->>+<<]<]>[->>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<<]>[->>>+<<[->>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>]<]>[->>+<<]<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>[-]>[-]>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]>[-]>>>>>[>>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<+<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]+>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<[->>[-<<+>>]<<[->>+>>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<]>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>->>>>>[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<<[->>>[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+>+<<<<]+>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<<<<<<<<<<]>>[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]<<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>[-<<<<+>[<->-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<[->+<]>>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>[-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++[[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<-<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>-]+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>[-<<<->>>]+<<<[->>>->[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>-<[-<<<+>>>]<<<[->>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>->>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<[-]<<]>>]<<+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]+<<<<[->>>>-<<<<<<.>>]>>>>[-<<<<<<<.>>>>>>>]<<<[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>>>[>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>[-]>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>+++++++++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>+>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+[-]>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>[-]+>>>]<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+>>[>+>>>>[-<<<<->>>>]<<<<[->>>>+<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<+<<<<<<<[>>>>>[->>+<<]<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>[<->-<<<+>>>]<[->+<]>>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>-<<<<[-]+<<<]+>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<->>>>>>>]+<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>->>[>>>>>[->>+<<]>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>[<->-<<<+>>>]<[->+<]>>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>+++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>+<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>[-<<<<<->>>>>]+<<<<<[->>>>>->>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<->>>>>>>]+<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>-<<[-<<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]<<<+++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>-<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>]<<<<.>>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[-]>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>++++++++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>+>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>+[-]>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>[-]+>>]<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>+>[>+>>>>>[-<<<<<->>>>>]<<<<<[->>>>>+<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<+<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>[->>+<<]<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<+>[<->-<<+>>]<[->+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>-<<<<<[-]+<<<]+>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<->>>>>>>>]+<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>->[>>>>>>[->>+<<]>>>]<<<<<<<<<[>[-]<->>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<+>[<->-<<+>>]<[->+<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>+<<<<<<<]<+<<<<<<<<<]>+++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>[>>>>>>[-<<<<<<->>>>>>]+<<<<<<[->>>>>>->>[-<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]+>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>+<]]+>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<->>>>>>>>]+<<<<<<<<[->>>>>>>>-<<[-<<<<<<+>>>>>>]<<<<<<[->>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>[-]+>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>>]>[-]+<]]+>[-<[>>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>]<<<<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]>>>>[-]<<<+++++[-[->>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>>>>>>]>>>>>->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-<<<<<<[<<<<<<<<<]]>>>]");

    return 0;
}
```
````

Comment: I'm looking forward to your posts when you have become an experienced C programmer! :-)

Comment: For loops: wouldn't it better to put loop start position in stack on each `[` encountered, and on `]` check top address of the stack (and on 0 in cell pop the stack)? IMO that will reduce number of traversings in `goToLoop` functions.

Comment: This is pretty good! One recommendation: Wrap your memory and instruction pointer into a "BrainFuckVM" struct. That will tidy that code up, and allow you to use some stronger types signatures on your functions. Plus from there you can get fancy and add snapshotting to save/restore vm state, you can add an "undo" to go back in time in the processing, etc.!

Comment: You lucky... I asked about mine a while back and I had to have a bounty put on it to get anything.

Answer (score 48):

This is a pretty reasonable start on a simple interpreter. Edward's suggestions are all good; a few additional suggestions:

---

```
interpret("+++++++++++++[->....
```

Please break up that long line.  C allows you to break up literal strings

```
"like "
"this."
```

---

```
void goToLoopEnd(char** ip) {
...
void goToLoopStart(char** ip) {
...
```

If you wrote these instead as

```
char * findLoopEnd(char* ip) {
...
char * findLoopStart(char* ip) { 
...
```

then you have functions that are just as useful, but *do not modify the input and are therefore testable with an independent unit test*.

This also eliminates a double pointer; double pointers are hard to reason about, so if there is a cheap and easy way to get rid of them, go for it.

This also enables you to improve the contract of these methods; for example, you could return null if there is no matching bracket. Which then brings up...

---

Aside from that, my biggest problem with your interpreter is that it has undefined behaviours all over the place if the program is not valid. What happens if there is an unmatched `[`?  What happens if the pointer goes *before* available memory?  Bad stuff, that's what. **A good interpreter is safe no matter what its input, and gives good diagnostics to the user when the input is bad.**  Always structure an interpreter so that it detects bad inputs, because it *will* get bad inputs.

In particular, note that Brainfuck does not specify what happens when the tape pointer becomes negative; does the tape "wrap around?", is it an error, is there supposed to be an infinite tape in both directions?  The conservative thing to do is to make it an error, but you haven't even done that; you just do something undefined.

---

Once you have the undefined behaviours under control, consider the cost of doing a linear search for matching brackets all the time.  It is almost always more efficient to scan the source code *once*, make a note of the locations of all matching pairs of brackets, and then when you hit a bracket you just do a lookup of the destination rather than a linear search for it. Yes, a linear search is fast if the program is small, but the program might not be small.

This step works to support the previous issue; if you record matching brackets before you run the program, you guarantee that every bracket is matched!

Comment: Strangely, there are no standard diagnostics requirements for Brainfuck interpreters.  Your note about checking for bad input is an important one!

Comment: I agree with your logic about undefined behavior but I find it ironic we are complaining about it on a question written in C. :)

Comment: @CaptainMan: That is somewhat ironic, yes. The given implementation turns undefined behaviour in the BF language into undefined behaviour in the C language! The better approach is to define the behaviour in the BF language, and then implement that so that there is no UB in the C implementation.

Comment: +1, was about to write an answer about using an O(1) map / dictionary data structure to find branch targets (possibly as simple as an array of `char*` or `unsigned` indexed by offset within the BF program), but you already mentioned that.  Also that `depth` or `nest_depth` might be a clearer var name than `searching`.

Comment: I wanted to store the bracket locations (as I did in my Python implementation) but I couldn't figure out how I would go about doing that in C. I used a dictionary in Python but isn't implementing a hash map a bit overkill for a project of this size?

Comment: Nvm, a friend helped me. I'll use an array of "matching brackets" structs, then binary search it.

Comment: @Ghost: Whether any choice is "over engineering" depends entirely on the requirements of the client *who is you*. You moved to C from Python, you say, because the performance was not good enough; you're the only person who knows if the performance is *still* not good enough. I imagine that you also chose C because it's a language you wish to learn, and *implementing simple data structures like hash maps is a great way to learn a new language*.

Comment: @Ghost: See my earlier comment: the very simplest form of this (and efficient if it fits in your CPU's L1d or at least L2 cache) is an array of `unsigned` offsets, or of `char*`, indexed by offset within the BF program.  Or with your size fixed at 30k, you can save space by making the bracket-match table `static unsigned short matching_bracket[30000];`.  Having half the cache footprint is worth it; most CPU architectures have relatively efficient narrow loads that zero-extend a short to int or pointer-width.  This is certainly true on x86, which you probably care most about optimizing for.

Comment: For small BF programs, only the first `n` elements of that array will get used, so the actual "hot" footprint is nice and small.

Comment: @Peter I think you confused the code segment size (unlimited) with the data segment size (min 30000). For what you intend to express, it's also more precise to use `uint16_t` than `unsigned short`.

Comment: @RolandIllig: oh yes, right.  I was thinking for some reason there was also an upper limit on program length, or just got mixed up. >.<  `unsigned short` was on purpose though; you don't need the program to fail to run on systems without the optional `uint16_t` fixed-width type, and it has a minimum size of 16-bit so it is safe if the program upper limit was that small.  (I think all modern systems do have `uint16_t`, though, so no real problem with using that, except maybe on a 24-bit word-addressable DSP where CHAR_BIT = 24.)

Comment: @Peter Ah, yes, thanks for the DSP reminder.

Answer (score 28):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.  In all, it seems to be nice, straightforward code that does what it needs to do.  Good start!

### Use only required `#include`s

The code has `#include <stdbool.h>` but doesn't use booleans.  It also appears that nothing from `<stdlib.h>` is used either. Only include files that are actually needed.

### Avoid the use of global variables

I see that `ptr` and indirectly, `mem` are used only within `interpret()` but they are declared as global variables. It's generally better to explicitly pass variables your function will need or declare them within the appropriately smallest possible scope rather than using the vague implicit linkage of a global variable.  In this case, both `mem` and `ptr` could be local variables within `interpret()`.  Use `memset` if you need to zero the contents.

### Use const where practical

The `interpret()` function does not modify the contents of the `code` pointer it is passed, so it should be declared `const`:

```
void interpret(const char* code) { /*...*/ }
```

This also means that `ip` can be `const` and then also that the arguments to the other functions can be, too.

### Declare local routines `static`

If you declare `goToLoopEnd` and `goToLoopStart` as `static`, the compiler will know that they can never be called outside this one file.  With that information, much more optimization might be done, such as inlining the code.

### Let the compiler generate code

When a C program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so it is not necessary to write `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

Comment: I agree with all of these suggestions except for the last one. I prefer the return value to be explicit. main is the only function where omitting the return value is allowed (except for void functions), so including it there as well makes the code more consistent. I do not see explicit guidance on this in the C++ core guidelines though, so it seems to be a matter of preference.

Comment: `mem` being inside `interpret` might be a stretch. Probably would be easier to dynamically-allocate `ptr`.

Comment: @MitchLindgren it is solely a matter of preference, but it is good to know about that aspect of the standard either way.

Comment: @JL2210: Most efficient but still good style: `static unsigned char mem[30000] = {0};` *inside `interpret`*.  If you know how much zeroed memory you want, you might as well statically allocate it in the BSS instead of dynamically with `calloc`.  Although for practical purposes, using a big `calloc` might put it farther from anything else and give more protection against out-of-bounds writes (simple segfault instead of maybe corrupting `.data` or other BSS objects).  In C terms a malformed BF program can cause UB in this interpreter either way; in mainstream implementations the details matter.

Comment: If you don't include `stdbool.h`, replace `unsigned char mem[30000] = {0};` by `static unsigned char mem[30000];`, prototype by `int main(void)`, and **don't** follow that last suggestion, then your code is now compatible with `C89`, and many more compliers are open to you.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Edward's point with "const": It's good practice to properly qualify all constant data, not so much for optimization (see http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/081.htm) as for displaying the author's intent, and for preventing errors. `const` is infectious, so you'll have to change all function signatures and pointer declarations operating on the constant brainfuck code.

That you can initialize a `char *` with a literal at all is pure legacy: K&R C did not have `const` (which reflected the fact that one could (I think) write anywhere in memory on then-typical machines like the PDP11). So there was already a lot of code out there which would break, and even after 1989 a lot of people didn't use const.

Back to your program: I do not know brainfuck; a brainfuck program could well be self-modifying like a Turing machine. That it doesn't do that can be expressed in C, preventing *accidental* write attempts as well.

Incidentally this change makes your program valid C++, another thing I find good practice, even if [Lightness Races with Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-with-monica) will probably disagree: So cast your `malloc`s if you have any (even if [unwind disagrees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3150802)), cast assignments to enums if you have any, and const your consts.

Comment: BF programs are, thank goodness, not self-modifying. A BF program acts like a Turing Machine with two tapes, a finite, read-only tape for the program, and a writable, infinite tape for the data. Since BF is Turing Complete, you can of course write a simulation of a TM in BF; that's left as an exercise. :)

Comment: Making code be also valid C++ is generally good, but not when it means casting `malloc` IMO.  Re: writeable strings: some PDP-11 models do have memory protection ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11#Models)).  Early Unix was developed on PDP-11; perhaps it didn't enforce read-only pages, or toolchains put string literals in the `.data` section.  Note that `char *p = "hello"` is not problematic if you never actually write through the pointer.  But yes, that will segfault on modern Unix systems, unless you compiled with a compiler like GCC3 or older with `gcc -fwriteable-strings`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, interesting! (Both the PDP11 and gcc info).

Comment: @EricLippert you haven't than seen "fukyorbrain" yet, two BF programs that have "multiple" threads and modify each other :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answers: These function declarations

```
int foo();
int bar() { }
```

do *not* declare a prototype for foo respectively bar. In consequence, this is a legal implementation of foo:

```
int foo(int a) { }
```

And this is a likely illegal call to bar, however the compiler can't warn:

```
bar(42);
```

To provide a prototype, add void inside the parenthesis to make it a parameter-list (instead of the C89 identifier list) and all of the above would yield compile time errors:

```
int foo(void);
int bar(void) {}
```

This is due to Cs history of K&R style function declarations and definitions:

```
int foo();

int foo(a)
int a;
{
   /* do something */
}
```

Compatibility is great, but I don't think you should go lower than C99 if not explicitly needed, especially if it lessens the likelihood of severe bugs ;)